# Is there a way to add the value that my button puts into a form field instead of replacing the input each time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

I'm currently trying to create a few buttons whose input I'd like to be displayed inside a form field. I've been able to create the buttons and make it so they put a value inside a form field. My goal is to have basically a 4-digit number in the form field but my code can only do single-digit numbers. For example, if I want to have 1234 in the form field I'd have to press buttons 1, 2, 3, and 4. But currently, these buttons only put their own designated values out and replace the value instead of adding it.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const areaField = document.getElementById("areaname_fill");

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    areaField.value = button.dataset.area;
  });
});


function myFunction() {
  var res = document.getElementById("areaname_fill").value
  var text;

  if (res == 1) {
    text = "result: 1";

  } else if (res >= 2 && res <= 9) {
    text = "result: 2-9";

  } else {
    text = "result: sorry";
  }
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
html * {
  font-family: Lato !important;
}

.buttons {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<div class="form-group">
  <label></label>
  <input type="text" name="areaname_fill" id="areaname_fill" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="1">
      1
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="2">
      2
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="3">
      3
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="4">
      4
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="3">
      5
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="5">
      6
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="6">
      7
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="7">
      8
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="8">
      9
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="9">
      Del
    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-area="0">
      0
    </button>

  <button class="button" role="button" button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" data-area="" data-square="">Go</button>
</div>

<p id="res">result:
  <p>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = text;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML + text;
```